# AzureStaticWebApp, Angular App, is failing on DevOps Pipeline

Tags: angular, azure-devops, azure-deployment, azure-static-web-app

I have an Angular app and it is deploying on Azure Static Web App through the Azure DevOps pipelines. It was working for almost more than a year but since last three days I'm getting error.DevOps pipeline Job run is failing in third stage i.e. Deploy Azure Static Web App.

The .yml file I'm using

```
# Node.js with Angular
# Build a Node.js project that uses Angular.
# Add steps that analyze code, save build artifacts, deploy, and more:
# https://docs.microsoft.com/azure/devops/pipelines/languages/javascript
trigger:
- main
pool:
  vmImage: ubuntu-latest
steps:
- task: AzureStaticWebApp@0
  inputs:
      app_build_command: "npm install --legacy-peer-deps"
      app_location: "/"
      api_location: "api"
      output_location: "dist/angular-sample-app"
  env:
      azure_static_web_apps_api_token: $(deployment_token_prod)
```

Please check below build logs

**Platform:**

```
Operation performed by Microsoft Oryx

Detecting platforms...
Detected following platforms:
  nodejs: 16.18.0
Version '16.18.0' of platform 'nodejs' is not installed. Generating script to install it...
Detected the following frameworks: Angular,Typescript
```

**NodeJs Version:**

```
Downloading and extracting 'nodejs' version '16.18.0' to '/opt/nodejs/16.18.0'...
Detected image debian flavor: bullseye.
Downloaded in 0 sec(s).
Verifying checksum...
Extracting contents...
performing sha512 checksum for: nodejs...
Done in 1 sec(s).

Removing existing manifest file
Creating directory for command manifest file if it does not exist
Creating a manifest file...
Node Build Command Manifest file created.

Using Node version:
v16.18.0

Using Npm version:
8.19.2
```

**Error:**

```
npm ERR! While resolving: angular11-sample-app@0.0.0
npm ERR! Found: @angular/compiler@13.2.7
npm ERR! node_modules/@angular/compiler
npm ERR!   @angular/compiler@"~13.2.0" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer @angular/compiler@"13.3.12" from @angular/localize@13.3.12
npm ERR! node_modules/@angular/localize
npm ERR!   peer @angular/localize@"^13.0.0" from @ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap@11.0.1
npm ERR!   node_modules/@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap
npm ERR!     @ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap@"^11.0.0" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! See /root/.npm/eresolve-report.txt for a full report.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /root/.npm/_logs/2023-02-10T08_09_53_305Z-debug-0.log


---End of Oryx build logs---
Oryx has failed to build the solution.

##[error]Error: The process '/usr/bin/bash' failed with exit code 1
```

Answer (score 1):

You're going to want to set the correct version of Node for your pipeline. Try and use the same version as your local development environment to avoid headaches. You should be able to use the task:

```
NodeTool@0
  inputs:
    versionSpec: '{Your desired version of node} ex: 14'
```

Also, If I'm not completely wrong, you're going to want to perform an `npm run build --production` (or similar) at some point. `npm install` isn't going to generate the necessary files in `dist/{appname}`